# Stacking multiple KDE plots vertically in panels of a facet_wrap()

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-science, facet, facet-wrap

Below is the plot that I am trying to modify. Every panel has three superimposed KDEs. I am wondering if I can plot the three KDEs in separate tiny sub-panels, stacked in rows with a shared x-axis and maybe the free y-axis. Such that, in the end, each of the 18 panels in the figure below will have three sub-panels stacked in rows with a single KDE per row. Here is an example figure http://cytoforum.stanford.edu/download/file.php?id=373&mode=view. The code that generates this figure is below the figure.

Thanks for any suggestions.

[image]

```
q <- ggplot(data = clust_stim, aes(x = marker_exp , fill = distribution)) +
        geom_density(size = 1, alpha = 0.25) +
        labs(x = "marker expression", title = paste0("Cluster: ", cl, "; Stim Type: ", st))

kde_plot <- p + facet_wrap( ~ state_marker, nrow = 3, ncol = 6, scales = "free_y") +
theme( axis.text = element_text( size = 14 ),
                 axis.text.x = element_text( size = 20 ),
                              axis.text.y = element_text( size = 20 ),
                              axis.title = element_text( size = 20, face = "bold" ),
                                           strip.text = element_text(size = 20),
                                           plot.title = element_text(size=22, face = "bold"))

ggsave(paste0("test.png"), plot = kde_plot, device = "png",
                  path = file.path(figures_folder, "kde_plots"), width = 26, height = 18, dpi = 300)
```

Comment: not exactly what you want, but you may get close to that by using `facet_grid(distribution ~ state_marker)`.

Comment: I would recommend the ggridges package https://github.com/wilkelab/ggridges

Comment: @teunbrand thanks it worked. ggridges is cool.